# SQL Server Populate replication server from DPM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, replication, transactional-replication

I've inherited an old SQL Server database with 4 machines: production_server(2008.r2), DPM_server(DPM 2007), and two replication_server1(2008.r2) replication_server2(2012). SQL Server had to be reinstalled on replication_server2, and so all data on that machine was lost.

I need to get transaction replication from production_server to this server back online without hammering the production server to create the initial snapshot.

Is it possible to use my DPM server to provide a recent copy of the data, Either via a Backup or snapshot?

Or, Is it possible to have replication_server1 provide the initial snapshot, and then point it to the production_server publication once everything has caught up?

I haven't been able to find clear answers in the documentation, thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/initialize-a-transactional-subscription-without-a-snapshot). 2nd option you asked is also possible if you can take a downtime. If you can, let me know. I will outline the steps.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I can accept some downtime on replication_server1. I did see the article you mentioned, it wasn't clear to me whether after loading the backup from replication_server1 onto replication_server2, if I could then subscribe replication_server2 to the publication on production_server. 

If that's possible I would appreciate the steps!

Comment: If your are using backup I would use it from production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This steps will implement your second option.

> Or, Is it possible to have replication_server1 provide the initial
>   snapshot, and then point it to the production_server publication once
>   everything has caught up?

You will setup replication normally between repl1 and repl2.  Use the same distribution server that you will use when you setup prod-->repl2 server.

Once downtime start (confirm app servers are not making any new connection/writing to Production publishing articles):

1. Continue running the distribution agent jobs till undelivered command count is zero on both prod-->repl1 and repl1-->repl2. This is absolutely critical for this approach to work.
2. Stop the distribution agent job/jobs.
3. Remove replication (publisher and subscriber only) but keep the distributor as is.
4. Reinstall replication between prod-->repl2 with 'replication support only' when running `sp_addsubscription`. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addsubscription-transact-sql).
5. Run snapshot jobs. It will not resync your table schema+data, rather create system objects if any missing.

> replication support only  Provides automatic generation at the
>   Subscriber of article custom stored procedures and triggers that
>   support updating subscriptions, if appropriate. Assumes that the
>   Subscriber already has the schema and initial data for published
>   tables. When configuring a peer-to-peer transactional replication
>   topology, ensure that the data at all nodes in the topology is
>   identical. For more information, see Peer-to-Peer Transactional
>   Replication.
>
> Not supported for subscriptions to non-SQL Server publications.

You can use this query to find undelivered commands in distribution database.

```
SELECT ss.srvname AS publisher, 
       [name]     AS Agent, 
       publication, 
       a.publisher_db, 
       subscriber_db, 
       art.article, 
       art.destination_object, 
       art.source_object, 
       undelivcmdsindistdb, 
       delivcmdsindistdb, 
       s.article_id, 
       agent_id, 
       a.publisher_id, 
       subscriber_id 
FROM   distribution.dbo.msdistribution_status AS s WITH (nolock) 
       FULL OUTER JOIN distribution.dbo.msdistribution_agents AS a WITH (nolock) 
                    ON s.agent_id = a.id 
       JOIN master.dbo.sysservers AS ss WITH (nolock) 
         ON a.publisher_id = ss.srvid 
       JOIN distribution.dbo.msarticles AS art WITH (nolock) 
         ON s.article_id = art.article_id 
WHERE  subscriber_db <> 'virtual' 
       AND subscriber_db = 'SubscriberDBName' 
ORDER  BY undelivcmdsindistdb DESC 
COMPUTE sum(undelivcmdsindistdb)
```